# Passing URL Parameters with ? into POST Request

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

Since the URL is behind a server only people with login can access i have used example.com in my question

I read several posts on passing URL Parameters into post request of Python.If I have a URL like http://example.com/FileView?page=locations, how do i pass FileView?page=locations into the post request

I have tried the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
import random 
import urllib3
import os
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint
url='https:abc.com'
urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Referer": "http://example.com/locations.jsp",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"}
with requests.session() as s:
    r=s.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
    item_body={"fileType": "csv",
               "fileAction": "Download"}
    data1={"page":"locations"}
    r2=s.post(url,params=(data1),data=(item_body),headers=headers,verify=False)
    print(r2.text)
```

I also tried passing in FileView with ? and blank string,it doesnt work still.Trying to directly access the http://example.com/FileView?page=locations gives me a 500 server error. I tried convering the dict data to json but still couldnt figure it out

The form data here consists of only two items i sepcified in my dict.
The actual output is downloading a csv file.Instead all i get is html page of referrer from the header.What mistake am I doing?